# iOS 5 local notifications and lock screen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uilocalnotification

I have an app that has its own states. My aim is to fire local notification when state changes - while in back ground [so far I did] but problem is: can I keep these (or at least one of them) notifications on the lock screen all the time? So if you get notification you can slide through it into app every time you got lock screen?

I've got an idea to run NSTimer with - let's say one second interval, and fire local notification each time interval... but i guess some will say it's against 'long life' battery policy... as far as I know you cannot detect lock screen from inside the app

Anybody?
thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not only the battery problem but SPAM. With iOS5 you can view all the notifications in the menu dragged from the top of the device screen. If you will keep sending those notifications the menu will be filled with unnecessary notifications. Moreover users phone will constantly vibrate...

Comment: vibrations - got it, certainly cons in this case, but if I got it right from [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7773584/can-i-programmatically-clear-my-apps-notifications-from-the-ios-5-notification) you can clear those notifications from menu

Comment: Sure you can clear it, but the phone will still constantly vibrate, or if the sound is on it will ring all the time. Why is it necessary to keep the notification always on?

Comment: i've got a task to be 1000% sure if it can be done, so that's why I'm trying to find a hole in everything, before I'll tell client it's off the table - I agree that it would be extremely frustrating, but as I said, got to be sure ;)

Comment: Tell your client it is possible, and provide him with your solution, only tell him that this will possibly be rejected by apple, and can be considered SPAM which can leed to account suspension.

Comment: thanks a lot man :)
btw I didn't expected an answer so quick, so you made my day ;) cheers