# remove push notification once it is accepted by user

Tags: iphone, ios5, apple-push-notifications

I am pushing some text to an iPhone app. once the message is accepted and processed in the app I still see the message in the notification area and if I accept it again the message get duplicated in the app.

how I can avoid that? Is there away to remove it from the notification area once the push is accepted.

In other words, once

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
      didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
```

is executed, I want to remove the notification from the notification area.

Comment: is it a local or remote notification?

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7821985/428442 . The trick, apparently, is that the app badge value has to change. So set it to 1 and then to 0, and that is supposed to remove the notification from the notification center.

Comment: it looks the link you provided talks about local notification. I am looking for removing Remote notifications. and I am not using bag number. –

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Setting the badge value to 1 or some value first then set it back to 0 worked. Like the following:

```
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:1];
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
```

Comment: @shebelaw Above code will help to remove all the notification from notification center. But is there any way to remove single notification which we have selected from notification center.

Answer (score 1):

Try this maybe?

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
```

Comment: I set this just before     `- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo`   completes.